# ObjectMapper convertValue error java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["id"]

Tags: java, objectmapper

I have the following problem to convert this json into an Object with ObjectMapper

```
"content": {
        "id": "5e65826f61383237c61f0898",
        "path": "5e65826f61383237c61f0898",
        "owner": "dfadfafdaf",
        "name": "My Folders",
        "parent": "root",
        "color": "rgb(94,94,94)",
        "forms": {
            "201318189217050": {
                "id": "201318189217050",
                "username": "dfadfadfad",
                "title": "Clone of Software Survey Form",
                "height": "0",
                "status": "ENABLED",
                "created_at": "2020-05-11 20:23:21",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-11 20:23:21",
                "last_submission": null,
                "new": "0",
                "count": "0",
                "type": "CARD",
                "url": "https://form.jotform.com/201318189217050"
            },
            "201284561879666": {
                "id": "201284561879666",
                "username": "testeataeta",
                "title": "Software Survey Form",
                "height": "0",
                "status": "ENABLED",
                "created_at": "2020-05-08 10:26:16",
                "updated_at": "2020-05-10 19:01:13",
                "last_submission": null,
                "new": "0",
                "count": "0",
                "type": "CARD",
                "url": "https://form.jotform.com/201284561879666"
            }
        },
        "subfolders": [
            {
                "id": "5eb9ee338b85ab179301cb56",
                "path": "5e65826f61383237c61f0898,5eb9ee338b85ab179301cb56",
                "owner": "testestsetes",
                "name": "outros forms",
                "parent": "5e65826f61383237c61f0898",
                "color": "#fe9a02",
                "forms": [],
                "subfolders": []
            },
            {
                "id": "5eb9ee5ea3636c4c9429fee5",
                "path": "5e65826f61383237c61f0898,5eb9ee5ea3636c4c9429fee5",
                "owner": "testesteset",
                "name": "outros forms 2",
                "parent": "5e65826f61383237c61f0898",
                "color": "#ffe49b",
                "forms": [],
                "subfolders": []
            }
        ]
    }
```

DTO mapped to Json

```
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE)
@Builder
public class ResponseFoldersDTO {

    private final String id;
    private final String path;
    private final String owner;
    private final String name;
    private final String parent;
    private final String color;
    private final Map<String, ResponseFormDTO> forms;
    private final List<Map<String, ResponseFoldersDTO>> subfolders;
}
```

Method created to call the service and map the return

```
public ResponseFoldersDTO getFoldersUserAccount() {

        HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(getHeaders());
        ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> response = restTemplate
                .exchange(
                        URL, 
                        GET, 
                        httpEntity, 
                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});

        return objectMapper.convertValue(
                response.getBody().get("content"),
                ResponseFoldersDTO.class);
    }
```

Debug before calling ObjectMapper.convertValue()

[image]

Error when trying to deserialize the subfolder array :

Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `br.com.service.jotform.ResponseFoldersDTO` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('5eb9ee338b85ab179301cb56')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1] (through reference chain: br.com.service.jotform.ResponseFoldersDTO.ResponseFoldersDTO["subfolders"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["id"])

Answer (score 0):

You have made the constructor private @RequiredArgsConstructor(access = PRIVATE).
Try removing private access.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @MotivatedMind I left the access as PUBLIC same error was returned to me.